# Not able to create new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am suddenly facing some issue while running few commands like `rails -v`  or `rails new project_name`.

I am actually having rails 5 successfully installed on my macbook pro. But sometime back I tried to clone an old rails project and ran bundle install and from then I am facing this issue. It says 
`in 'raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rails-3.0.1, because bundler-1.16.1 conflicts with bundler (~> 1.0.0) (Gem::ConflictError)`.

[image: Screenshot attached for more info!]Can anybody please help?

Comment: It seems bundler version issue. You can check this link: https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/2081

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update to bundler, run following command to update bundler

```
gem update bundler
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you may update rails

```
gem update rails
```

or may create new project with rails specific version(ex: 5.1.1) installed on mac.

```
rails _5.1.1_ new test_app
```

Comment: remove other rails versions

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update to bundler . You can run the following command.

'bundler update'